# Remove underscores between words so they don't appear in n-grams in R

Tags: r, quanteda

before running a topic model, I put n-grams, so words in 2-3 chunks could appear in my topic model afterward.

```
toks_data_ngrams <- tokens_ngrams(toks_data, n=2:3)
```

After this, however, my topic model includes so many words like
a_b, apple_banana, happy_hand.

How can I ignore those words with underscores? I don't want them to be included in my topic model. Is there any extra code for ngrams so ngrams don't catch words with underscore in between?
(I've already removed punctuations and symbols during the pre-processing).

Thanks so much for all your inputs in advance!

Comment: Can you provide a minimal data set? If you want to remove underscore from a string, you can use for instance `str_remove(your_string, "_")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tokens_ngrams` has a concatenator option. By default this is set to `_`. You can specify anything you want, a space for example:

```
tokens_ngrams(toks_data, n= 2:3, concatenator = " ")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude them using

```
toks_data_ngrams <- toks_data_ngrams[!grepl("_", toks_data_ngrams)]
```

In the future, always include reproducible examples in your questions